# Why is the button not working when not using setType()?

Tags: android, android-intent

When I'm using `i.setType("text/plain");`, then my button is working but when not using then it is not working.After clicking it is not giving options to open any app. Why so?. Help me please.

Here is the code for MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
                String text = et.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Email From Ankit's Own 
                Created App");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);

                if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where are `createChooser` ??

Comment: why asking why? if your code is working??

Answer (score 0):

You should use startActivity in following way :

```
                         try {
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                                        "Send email using..."));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        "No email clients installed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was needed for an email app, to get your data,

A more detail example to get shared file, you can look it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)